# How to get DAC fields display name in Selector When we are displaying data fields from joining 2 tables in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have one customSelector conatins 4 data fields from 2 Tables Join.
Here I am getting Tablename__FieldName as a Display in selector..

How can I see DAC Display names of Data fields for 2 tables Joined in A selector?

Comment: Could you post the DAC code where the selector is defined?

Comment: Do you have `PXUIFieldAttribute` on that field?

Comment: You need PXUIFieldAttribute on the field with the DisplayName property as Samvel suggested. You can override the DAC field with CacheAttached mechanism to add PXUIField in a graph extension if necessary.

Comment: PxSelectorAttribute attr=PXSelectorAttribute(bqljoinsearch,type of(customtable.fieldname).      In this scenario how can I give

Comment: My Selector Attribute is below

Answer (score 0):

LotSelector Attribute is below

In this scenario i am getting TableName_FieldName instead off DAC display name
[TSLotSerialNbr(typeof(TSProdMTranSplit.inventoryID), typeof(TSProdMTranSplit.subItemID),
typeof(TSProdMTranSplit.locationID), typeof(TSProdMTranSplit.lotSerialNbr),

[image]